# RxJS Observable: performing cleanup when the last subscription is disposed?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

What is the cleanest way to perform a side-effect when the **last subscription** for a RxJS Observable is disposed? This may occur **before the Observable has terminated**.

Let's say that I need a function returning an `Observable` that emits changes to a resource. I'd like to perform a cleanup action when *all subscriptions* have been disposed.

```js
var observable = streamResourceChanges(resource);
var subscription1 = observable.subscribe(observer1);
var subscription2 = observable.subscribe(observer2);
// ...
subscription1.dispose();  // Does not perform the cleanup
subscription2.dispose();  // Performs the cleanup
```

The only way I've found to define a subscription disposal action is to use [`Rx.Observable.create`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md). The last disposal can be handled by sharing a subscription, for example with [`Observable.prototype.singleInstance()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/singleinstance.md).

For example:

```js
function streamResourceChanges(resource) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(function(observer) {
        // Subscribe the observer for resource changes...
        // Return a cleanup function
        return function() {
            // Perform cleanup here...
            console.log("Cleanup performed!");
        };
    }).singleInstance();
}
```

Is there a neater way to define a side-effect for subscription disposal, similar to `doOnNext`, `doOnCompleted` or `doOnError`?

```js
var withCleanup = withoutCleanup.doOnDispose(function() {
    // Perform cleanup here...
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two choices come to mind depending upon your actual use case:

[.finally()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md)

```
source.finally(() => console.log("cleaning up")).singleInstance()
```

[.using()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/using.md)

```
Rx.Observable
    .using(
        // allocate some disposable resource during subscribe.
        // resource.dispose() will be called during unsubscribe.
        () => new SomeResource(),

        // use the disposable resource to create your observable
        // for example...
        resource => Rx.Observable.interval(resource.time))
    .singleInstance();
```

Comment: Thanks! The `using` method sounds like a valid alternative for `create`!

The `finally` callback runs only when the Observable terminates, which may not necessarily be the case when the last subscription is disposed. Sorry I wasn't very specific about this; I edited my question.

Comment: The documentation does not state it very well.  Finally actually calls the action when the subscription is disposed, which includes during termination or when you manually dispose the subscription.

Comment: I tried `finally` and you are totally correct! The documentation currently says nothing about this behavior (and it also has incorrect description for the callback parameter). So, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: `.finally()` has been *renamed* to the pipeable [`finalize()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize)